# How to debug C and Matlab code at the same time?

Tags: c, matlab, debugging

I have some Matlab `.m` files that use a C function I've created.

When Debugging in Matlab, or Visual-Studio, is there any way to run step by step both C and Matlab codes in a way that both Matlab a C variables remain usable for debug?

Comment: please clarify: How are you using this C code within Matlab? Is it within a `mex` function? Or are you calling a compiled program?

Comment: Is this question about C++ or about C.  Please clarify and either correct the question or the 'tag' used.

Comment: @Mefitico I'm using a mex function.

Comment: Then the best thing I know you can do is to create a mex-wrapper that calls your C function from a separate file, and develop tests for that C file in C. In the mex-wrapper, you can add lots of macro-removable `printf`s, so that you can basically follow the flow of everything. In Matlab, you can debug as usual. I'd find it very interesting to discover you could perform step-by-step debugging from Matlab into the MEX function. I don't expect MSVS to integrate with Matlab in this regard. But I'll be curious to check the answers that may appear here.

Answer (score 1):

This addresses only the MSVS half of your question...

The steps to use step-by-step debugging using *[Visual Studio are outlined here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-dll-projects?view=vs-2019)*.  This is just an except centering around a .dll that is hosted by a pre-existing application.  Matlab qualifies as a host application, whether it is also being run in debug mode, or not.

> Start debugging from the calling app
>
> The app that calls a DLL can be:
>
> ```
> An app from a Visual Studio project in the same or a different solution from the DLL.
> An existing app that is already deployed and running on a test or production computer.
> Located on the web and accessed through a URL.
> A web app with a web page that embeds the DLL.
> ```
>
> To debug a DLL from a calling app, you can:
>
> ```
> Open the project for the calling app, and start debugging by selecting Debug > Start Debugging or pressing F5.
>
> or
>
> Attach to an app that is already deployed and running on a test or production computer. Use this method for DLLs on websites or in web
> ```
>
> apps. For more information, see How to: Attach to a running process.
>
> Before you start debugging the calling app, set a breakpoint in the
>   DLL. See Using breakpoints. When the DLL breakpoint is hit, you can
>   step through the code, observing the action at each line. For more
>   information, see Navigate code in the debugger.
>
> During debugging, you can use the Modules window to verify the DLLs
>   and .exe files the app loads. To open the Modules window, while
>   debugging, select Debug > Windows > Modules. For more information, see
>   How to: Use the Modules window. Use the Immediate window
>
> You can *[also]* use the *Immediate window* to evaluate DLL functions or methods
>   at design time. The Immediate window plays the role of a calling app.
>   *[and so on....]*